# Finding extrema using Lagrange multiplier (confusion)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

Use Lagrange Multiplier to locate the maximum and minimum points and values of
$F(x, y, z) = 2x^2 − 2y + z^2$ subject to the constraint $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1.$

Using the lagrange multiplier, I obtain 4 equations:

$4x\:=\:\lambda 2x,$

$\:-2\:=\:\lambda \:2y,$

$\:2z\:=\:\lambda \:2z,$

$\:x^{2\:}+\:y^2=1$

Now dividing equation $1$ and $3$ by $2$:

$\frac{4x}{-2}\:=\:\frac{\lambda 2x}{\:\lambda \:\:2y},$

$\:\frac{\:2z}{-2}\:=\:\frac{\lambda \:2z}{\:\lambda \:\:2y},$

In means that:

$x\:=\:0 $ or $\:y\:=\:-\frac{1}{2},$  $\:z\:=\:0$ or $\:y\:=\:-1$

Now here is my problem, I am not too sure how to interpret these values. Do I just pick a combination of these values and sub them into equation 4 or the constraint equation and find the other variable ?

For example:

the combinations are:

$x\:=\:0 $ and $\:y\:=\:-\frac{1}{2},$ and find $z$

$x = 0$ and $\:y\:=\:-1$ and find $z$

$x\:=\:0 $ and  $z = 0$ and find $y$

$z\:=\:0$ or $\:y\:=\:-1$ and find $x$

$z\:=\:0 $ and $\:y\:=\:-\frac{1}{2},$and find $x$

But apparently this whole is not the correct
"match"? How do I find the correct ones? Thanks.

Comment: You are missing solutions... You need to be more systematic. Start with the first equation: you have that $\lambda = 2 \vee x=0$; now substitute each of these two cases in the other equations and see what happens. For instance, if $\lambda = 2$, you have that $y =- \frac 12$, $z = 0$ and $x = \pm \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$. So, you get two solutions from this first condition. Now see what happens when $x = 0$ and you'll get the other solutions.

**Note:** There is a $z^2$ missing in your last equation.

Comment: Hello Professor, thanks for the comment. for $x$ = 0, I have no $x$ in second or third equation what do I do?

Comment: Are they the only 2 conditions? Or Are there 2 conditions for each equation? Thanks

Comment: There are more conditions, but this is the first branching... For instance, after you concentrate on the case $x=0$, there will be further alternatives for the remaining variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The set of equations to be solved is
$$
\begin{cases}2x(2-\lambda) =0 \\ \lambda y = -1\\2z(1-\lambda)=0\\x^2+y^2+z^2 = 1 \end{cases}
$$

Starting with the first equation, we have that $x = 0 \vee \lambda =2$, so, two cases:

**CASE 1:** $\lambda =2$.

The remaining variables are computed from
$$
\begin{cases} 2 y = -1\\ -2z = 0\\ x^2+y^2+z^2 = 1\end{cases}
$$
This yields the solutions $\left(\pm\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}, -\frac 12, 0 \right)$

**CASE 2:** $x = 0$

The remaining variables must be computed  from
$$
\begin{cases}\lambda y =-1 \\ 2z(1-\lambda)=0\\y^2+z^2=1 \end{cases}
$$

Looking at the second equation in this system, we see two sub-cases:

**CASE 2.1:** $z = 0$ (and $x=0$)

The last equation becomes $y^2 = 0$ and the solutions that arise from this case are $(0,\pm 1, 0)$

**CASE 2.2:** $\lambda = 1$ (and $x=0$)

Here $y=-1$ from the first equation and $z=0$ from the last. This yields the solution $(0,-1,0)$

Comment: Hello Professor Pierre, one last thing, how many solutions are we expecting? We have $4$ different solutions here right? (including the plus or minus). Do we always expect $4$? Thanks

Comment: @AliceRathbone There is no way of guessing the number of solutions of general nonlinear systems of equations unless you actually start solving it.